# calling imagemagick 'identify' with google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use imagemagick in my Google Cloud function. The function is triggered by uploading a file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I have grander plans, but trying to get there one step at a time. Starting with identify.

```
    // imagemagick_setup
    const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
    const path = require('path');
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();

    exports.processListingImage = (event, context) => {
        const object = event.data || event; // Node 6: event.data === Node 8+: event
        const filename = object.name;
        console.log("Filename: ", filename);

        const fullFileObject = storage.bucket(object.bucket).file(object.name);

        console.log("Calling resize function");
        let resizePromise = resizeImage( fullFileObject );

        <more stuff>
    };


    function resizeImage( file, sizes ) {
        const tempLocalPath = `/tmp/${path.parse(file.name).base}`;

        return file
            .download({destination: tempLocalPath})
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Failed to download file.', err);
                return Promise.reject(err);
            })
            .then( () => {
                // file now downloaded, get it's metadata
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    gm( tempLocalPath )
                        .identify( (err, result) => {
                            if (err)
                            {
                                console.log("Error reading metadata: ", err);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("Well, there seems to be metadata: ", result);
                            }
                        });
                });
          });
    } // end resizeImage()
```

The local file path is: "/tmp/andy-test.raw". But when the identify function runs, I get an error:

```
identify-im6.q16: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-12MgKrSna0qp9U.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
```

Why is identify looking for a different file than what I (believe) I told it to look for? Eventually, I am going to resize the image and write it back out to Cloud Storage, but I wanted to get identify to run first..

Comment: I suspect ImageMagick may be interpreting your `.raw` extension as meaning something other than what your file is. Can you try naming it more appropriately?

Comment: I was wondering about that. My issue is that I don't necessarily know what type of file I'm getting (jpg, png, etc) when I'm pulling from my source (MLS Boards and their 'standard' RETS protocol). In many cases, I just get a bitstream and no filename. One of the reasons I want to use 'identify' was to get the file type.   I'll try the renaming, and if that works, see if I can poke their standard to get some more information

Answer (score 0):

Mark had the right answer - if I upload a jpg file, it works. Onto the next challenge.